# Regex extract first +- n Characters but also include the rest of the charactes until the end of the line

Tags: c#, regex

Please help:

I have the following expression that retrieves the first 1000 characters of a string up until the end of the word, however I would like it to grab the text up until the end of the line (\r\n)?

**Expression:**

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(mystring, @"^.{1,1000}\b(?<!\s)").Value
```

**Example text:**

> Whoo Hoo!! We made it through another year. Can you believe it? I can
>   hardly contain myself. This has been one bumpy ride. And now all of
>   that is over.\r\n\r\n Being a Taxi Driver can be quite rewarding in
>   more ways than one. There is nothing like it in the world!\r\n\r\n I
>   made some new friends and caught up with a couple old ones. I met new
>   people from all over the world and experienced a garden variety of
>   situations, all over a 12 hour period. \r\n\r\nTonight I had lots of
>   fun, though I can't help but to think of how disappointing it was for
>   everyone, financially, this year. I can remember a time when we would
>   have all booked and taken home about 3-4 times more than we did over
>   the past day. Buddy is my best friend. He is a small, blond, six and a
>   half year old Pekingese. He has been part of the family since he was
>   only three months old. He rode along on the front passenger seat as
>   one set of passengers came and went. watching intensely out the window
>   and paying close attention to where we were going and where we were
>   at. He would check out each person who entered the cab

(Currently it grabs the text till here)

> just by looking at them over. He was enjoying his New Year!\r\n\r\n

(I would like it to Grab the text until here)

> Around 1:30 AM I was crossing Ocean Blvd. A van ran out in front of
>   me. I slammed on the breaks and avoided a collision. Buddy was not
>   buckled in. His entire body slammed into the dash board and then he
>   dropped into the floor board. He was shaken and scared. Heck, I was
>   too. I was afraid that he was injured worse than the bump on his head
>   and his upset nervous system. It was at this moment I decided that it
>   was time for Buddy to go home and rest. I was glad that the dash is
>   built so high, otherwise Buddy would have met the wind shield.\r\n\r\n
>   You see, I feel like everything happens for a reason. At one moment my
>   mind started spinning, only lasting for a few seconds, and I realized
>   the there was a good reason I must have been sent to pick up each and
>   every one of the people whom I did this night. I set out each day with
>   a mission. Today I'll be in the right place, at the right time, to
>   meet the right people, for the betterment of all. \r\n\r\n 'I see
>   opportunity in every challenge.' \r\n\r\n This day did not short
>   change me on challenges, this is for sure. I know that I didn't do as
>   well as others, but did better than others. It seems, according to the
>   statics, that I may have faired out average. Over all I did well if
>   you ask me. Just look at the big picture. Note: This is not the order
>   of events of the evening.

Comment: aren't you just looking for the entire line then. Since every line by definition always has one & only one line end, just take the entire line. You probably don't need Regex's at all...

Comment: Never used Regex before, I would like it to find the line that contains the 1000th caracter and return everything up and until the end of this line ..

Answer (score 2):

```
"^(?<text>.{1,1000}[^\\]*)\\r\\n"
```

should work as it finds the corresponding \r\n, but only captures the text you want into the group "text".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Why not explain why this works, too?

Comment: it starts with the beginning of the text (^) , and then captures  any 1-1000 characters (.{1,1000}) followed by any number of not-escape-sequences ([^\\]*). then \r\n is a windows newline (CarriageReturn LineFeed).

Answer (score 1):

No regex needed. Try

```
mystring.Substring(0, mystring.LastIndexOf("\r\n", 1000));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, This works: mystring.Substring(0, mystring.IndexOf("\r\n", 1000)); but I would like to know how to do it using regex

Answer (score 0):

\r and \n are special "characters" in regex, respectively for, as you may expect, carriage-return and line-feed; so: let your regex scan until \r\n